# Checkding and de-registering document.ready() callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JQuery, it is possible to register a document.ready() listener by doing?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  alert("Document.ready.2")
});
```

1. Is there anyway to deregister that callback?
2. Is there anyway to check what callbacks are configured for the `document.ready()` event?

Comment: You should generally only need one, at most ?

Comment: True but you might also be integrating into a website which has several scripts.

Comment: In that case, no, there's no way to deregister them, or check what they do etc.

Comment: I don't know your reasons for 'deregistering' those listeners. Maybe you could write the code in those functions in such way that they execute conditionally.

Comment: @adeneo consider forming that into an answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I was thinking? It just takes a while. You probably could do this with namespacing, but that would mean `$(document).on('ready.first')` and `$(document).off('ready.first')` etc. but you shouldn't use `on` for the DOM ready handler, it's actually bad practice, so I was thinking maybe there was a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deregister `$(document).ready(func)`

But you can use a trick like this,

```
var tobeExecuted = true;
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if (tobeExecuted){
     alert("Document.ready.2");
  }
});

tobeExecuted = false; //simulating deregister
```

**But**

You can deregister `$(document).on("ready",func);`

```
$(document).on("ready",function(){
    alert();  //this wan't be executed
});

$(document).off("ready");
```

Comment: I don't think `$(document).on("ready", fn)` does what you expect it to do.

Comment: could you explain more? @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: `$(document).ready(alert.bind(null, "Hello"); $(document).on("ready", alert.bind(null, "World"))` what alerts did you get?

Comment: I'm getting 2 alerts "Hello" and "world". @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: I'm not, I'm getting one alert.

Comment: This only happens if you registered the event before the document is ready.